# FO-DICOM C-MOVE response: "Cannot understand"

Tags: server, dicom, fo-dicom

```
var cmove = new DicomCMoveRequest(AEServer, studyUID); // AEServer is my server name which listening for a C-STORE request.

var client = new DicomClient();
client.AddRequest(cmove);
client.Send(ip, port, false, AEClient, serverName);  // AEClient is a clinent name.
```

[image]
When i try send a C-MOVE request to another a server, the server is sending to me response like this "C-MOVE response: Cannot understand".
Who knows that with my request is wrong?
Or who knows why the server is returning "Cannot understand"?
I do not have access to the "called" server logs.

I'm sorry for my english.

Comment: What kind of DICOM server are you calling? Have you tested the same call on other kinds of servers?

Comment: @AndersGustafsson, I'm calling a dicom pacs server. C-FIND is working good, but C-MOVE throws the error. I tested a program on both Conquest and ClearCanvas servers. On the ClearCanvas it works well. On the Conquest was necessary to add my program in a white list.

Comment: Then it sounds like you should look for the explanation in the PACS server. Does it support C-MOVE for studies, for example?

Comment: I think yes, because if it doesn't support C-MOVE it will send to me a "reject error".  I think the problem is in permissions, because same error was when I tried connect to Conquest server before when I added my server in a white list. I yesterday sent a message to the server administrators, but they are not answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that you are not sending the Query/Retrieve Level (0008, 0052) attribute or not filling it with proper value. Try adding Query/Retrieve Level attribute and populate it with string "STUDY" and send the C-MOVE.

Comment: It sends same error. Probably the server can't sends a C-STORE request to my server.

Comment: What is the AE Title you are sending as move destination? Is that AE listening on a port for processing C-Store request? Make sure server is aware of the IP and Port of the Move destination AE.

Comment: "AEServer" is AE Title of my server which listening for C-STORE requests. It works with servers which are running on my computer, but when I try make a connect with a computer in local network something is going wrong.

Comment: It is possible that you have windows firewall turned on and it is blocking the incoming connection from remote server. Try disabling the firewall and test again.